# file object resulting from `fileSystemFileEntry.file()` call is missing webkitRelativePath in chrome (but not firefox)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following FileSystemFileEntry object (obtained via drag-and-drop of the folder containing the file):

[image: FileSystemFileEntry object]

---

1. **Firefox:** On converting it to a File object via the `.file()` method, I get the following File object in firefox. The webkitRelativePath property is populated with the full path.

[image: File object in firefox]

---

2. **Chrome:** On converting it to a File object via the `.file()` method, I get the following File object in chrome. The webkitRelativePath property is an empty string.

[image: File object in chrome]

It seems chrome is losing the full path. Is there any way to ensure the File object retains the full path in chrome? Is this intended behaviour, or a chrome bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this issue, too.
A workaround I found is to set up the `webkitRelativePath` property by myself on the file object.

```
        const file: File = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => (item as FileSystemFileEntry).file(resolve, reject));
    Object.defineProperty(file, 'webkitRelativePath', {
      value: item.fullPath,
    });
```